# AJAX not Making POST request in FLASK

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

Have poured over SO and every blog and/or video I can find. I'm new to JS/AJAX/JQUERY, and have recently tried to incorporate these guys into my Flask apps, much to my current dismay. Trying to simply submit the form data to my MySQL DB via an AJAX call, without refreshing the page. This is far as I've gotten. Don't even see the post request being made in the inspector. Maybe it's not hitting the route? Here's my code:

Form HTML

```
<form name="race_form" id="race_form">
    <input type="text" id="characterID" value="{{ character.id }}" />
    <input type="text" id="raceID" value="{{ attribute.id }}" />
    <button type="submit" id="toggleoption-{{ attribute.attribute_name }}"
    class="btn btn-default char_gen_options_btn" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    background:url(/static/img/blacksmith.jpg) right center no-repeat; background-size:contain;
    background-color:#B5B6AF;font-weight:900;">Select {{ attribute.attribute_name }}</button>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#race_form').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var character_id = $('#characterID').val();
    var attribute_id = $('#raceID').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for('auth.register_race') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { character_id: character_id, attribute_id: attribute_id }
    });

  });
});
```

Flask View (committing to many to many table)

```
@auth.route('/register_race', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def register_race():
    character = Character.query.filter_by(id=request.form['characterID']).first()
    character.character_attributes.character_id = request.form['characterID']
    character.character_attributes.attribute_id = request.form['raceID']
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'result': 'success'})
```

And the tables from models.py that the view is referencing:

```
class Character(db.Model):
    """
    Create a Player Character table - all characters assigned to user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'characters'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    character_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    experience_points = db.Column(db.Integer)  # Refers to proprietary character build points
    character_lives = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    character_img = db.Column(db.String(300)) # Path to character img on server
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())
    last_update = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=func.now())
    # Keys
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary='user_character')
    attribute = db.relationship('Attribute', secondary='character_attributes')
    items = db.relationship('Items', secondary='inventory')
    files = db.relationship('File', secondary="character_files")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Character Name: {}>'.format(self.character_name)


class CharacterAttributes(db.Model):
    """
    Many to many table for characters and assigned attributes
    """
    __tablename__ = 'character_attributes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())
    last_update = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=func.now())
    amount_purchased = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # Keys
    character_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('characters.id'))
    attribute_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'))
    character = db.relationship('Character', backref=backref('character_attributes', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    attribute = db.relationship('Attribute', backref=backref('character_attributes', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```

Comment: Is your submit event being called? The way you can check is add a line console.log('called') in the submit function. Now when you click submit, does that print to the console.

Comment: The javascript written for ajax request is in seperate script file or same django template ?

Comment: Sorry all. The js is imported from: <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/return_race.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script> at the bottom of my page, and get 200's in my network console. I'll check the console log when I get home this evening. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So I think I figured out a bit of the issue. My form is wrapped up in a jinja loop that creates blocks of html based on the number of attribute id's sent into the page. This is making it so that each form has the same id. Not sure how to remedy this.